How to Pass ArrayList of Custom Objects Between Activities in Kotlin on Android Studio
I'm working on an Android project in Kotlin where I store user information in a custom object. I need to pass an ArrayList<CustomObject> from one activity to another and display the stored information in a list format.
I've tried reading various threads, but I encountered issues with serialization being less efficient than Parcelable. However, some methods like getParcelableArrayListExtra are deprecated.
What's the best way to pass an ArrayList<CustomObject> between activities in 2024?
Note: I understand this is a theoretical question, so I'm not including code. I'm looking for a current, efficient solution for passing data between activities.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android?rq=2

you can use
val customObjectList = arguments?.getParcelableArray("customObjectList")?.toList() as? List<CustomObject>

This approach ensures type safety and reduces the risk of runtime errors. It's also more efficient than using serialization.

This was a good option, but I went with using a Singleton class since it was a very simple implementation.
